# Unresolved External Symbol 'strcmpi' on Windows

Tags: c

While compiling my C project on Windows-10 platform using the 'icl' compiler, I am getting the below error:

> OLDNAMES.lib(strcmpi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   strcmpi OLDNAMES.lib(strcmpi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
>   symbol _strcmpi

Please help me to solve this issue. The value of LIB environment variable is:

```
echo %LIB%
```

> C:\Progra~2\Intel\\compiler\lib;C:\Progra~1\Micros~1\Lib\AMD64\atlmfc;C:\Progra~1\Micros~1\Lib\AMD64\;C:\Progra~1\Micros~1\Lib\;C:\Progra~2\Intel\\compiler\lib\intel64;

I am not sure which Library I have missed here.

Comment: This would be why you should avoid non-standard functions for trivial things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since the OLDNAMES.lib is a system library , I don't have the source code with me. The file 'OLDNAMES.lib ' is present under C:\Progra~1\Micros~1\Lib\AMD64\. So in this case what to do ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `stricmp` instead which is an extremely common extension to `<string.h>`, but note that it also is **not** a standard C function. Failing that, try `_stricmp`.

You can `#DEFINE` `strcmpi` to `stricmp` which is quite a common thing to do when targeting multiple platforms.

I tend to use `_stricmp` in my source code, and `#DEFINE` the relevant function to it in multiplatform headers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since the OLDNAMES.lib is a system library , I don't have the source code with me. The file 'OLDNAMES.lib ' is present under C:\Progra~1\Micros~1\Lib\AMD64\. So in this case what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what `strcmpi` does, you could implement it yourself and link the result into your program. If it does what I think it does, simply writing

```
extern int
strcmpi(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    return _stricmp(a, b);
}
```

should do the trick on Windows.